# Не работает метод subscribe rxjava2 при преобразовании Flowable<List<Trainer>> в Flowable<List<Trainer2>>

Tags: android, rxjava, room

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться - уже три дня ломаю голову и никак не могу понять что я делаю не правильно.

Необходимо передать список тренеров Flowable> из локальной базы данных SQlite Android (Room) для вывода на экран в RecyclerView в Activity. 
Перед передачей, модель Trainer необходимо преобразовать в Trainer2, однако, после этого, метод ShowAllTrainers внутри subscribe не вызывается.

Вот этот метод:

```
    @Override
    public void getAllTrainersFromLocalDB() {
  myDatabase.trainersDao().getAll()
                .flatMap(list -> Flowable.fromIterable(list))//emits one by one
                .map(trainerEntity -> CustomMapper.trainerEntityTotrainerModel(trainerEntity))
                .toList()
                .toObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(trainersList -> {
                            view.ShowAllTrainers(trainersList, null, null);
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            view.ShowErrorMessage(throwable.getMessage());
                        });
    }
```

Вот класс CustomMapper, который преобразовывает модель:

```
public class CustomMapper {

    public static Trainer2 trainerEntityTotrainerModel(Trainer trainer){
        Trainer2 trainerOfNewType = new Trainer2();

        trainerOfNewType.setAbout(trainer.getAbout());
        trainerOfNewType.setEducation(trainer.getEducation());
        trainerOfNewType.setId(trainer.getId());
       //...
        return trainerOfNewType;
    }
```

Программа при этом не зависает, приложение продолжает работу - отображается Activity, но без RecyclerView. getAll() - это метод из интерфейса DAO:

```
 @Dao
 public interface TrainersDao { 

 @Query("SELECT * FROM trainers") 
 Flowable<List<Trainer>> getAll(); 
    //...
    }
```

А если убрать все преобразования(flatMap, map, toList, toObservable) и просто получить исходный `Flowable<List<Trainer>>`, то subscribe работает корректно (например выводит в log количество элементов). Это выглядит так:

```
    myDatabase.trainersDao().getAll()
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(trainersList -> { 
       String size = Integer.toString(trainersList.size());
       Log.i("Size", size);
     }
```

Буду очень благодарна за любую помощь.

Comment: А что происходит? Просто ничего не происходит, или программа зависает?

Comment: И да - ваш trainerEntityTotrainerModel ошибок не содержит. Лучше покажите что за getAll вы вызываете...

Comment: Не зависает, приложение продолжает работу - отображается Activity, но без RecyclerView. getAll() - это метод из интерфейса DAO:   @Dao
public interface TrainersDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM trainers")
    Flowable<List<Trainer>> getAll(); //...}

Comment: И если убрать все преобразования и просто получить   исходный Flowable<List<Trainer>> то subscribe работает корректно (например выводит в log количество элементов):
      myDatabase.trainersDao().getAll().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(trainersList -> {
                       String size =    Integer.toString(trainersList.size());
                          Log.i("Size",  size);}

Comment: Светлана, ваш код в комментариях - нечитаем. Пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" и укажите всю необходимую информацию в самом вопросе.

Comment: Павел, я дополнила вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по документации на Room, возврат Flowable из DAO-интерфейса означает бесконечную последовательность "живых" обновлений. То есть у вас не список объектов, а последовательность списков.

А оператор `toList` собирает все в **один** список. И не заканчивает работу пока последовательность-источник не закончится. А та не заканчивается, потому что бесконечна.

---

Предлагаю начать решать задачу с начала. Вам нужно преобразовать одну последовательность в другую - и это делается оператором map. Не flatMap+map+toList, а просто map! Его и нужно писать первым:

```
myDatabase.trainersDao().getAll().map(list ->
```

Ну а дальше - нужно просто преобразовать один список в другой:

```
    list.stream().map(CustomMapper::trainerEntityTotrainerModel).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: вызов stream() требует API level 24,  а у меня мin указан 15

Comment: Я же правильно поняла, Вы предлагаете вот так сделать:        myDatabase.trainersDao().getAll()
               .map(list -> list.stream()
                                .map(CustomMapper::trainerEntityTotrainerModel)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()...

Comment: @Светлана тогда пишите преобразование списков самостоятельно, это не такой сложный алгоритм. Да, вы поняли правильно.

Comment: Павел, спасибо Вам огромное и низкий поклон. Не верю своему счастью, но это работает :)) Может кому еще пригодится - вот как может выглядеть этот самый метод map:       myDatabase.trainersDao().getAll().map(list -> {
                    ArrayList<Trainer2> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(Trainer item:list) {
                        newList.add(CustomMapper.trainerEntityTotrainerModel(item));
                    }
                    return newList;
                })